# How to create a strongly typed collection that only contains one element per type

Tags: c#, collections, strong-typing

I'm in the process of trying to create a collection that will only contain one element per type.  Each of the types will have to subclass a root type however, so that there is a commonality.
I've done some research and am wondering if I'm on the right track here or if there are some improvements that can be made:

```
class TypedList<T> : Dictionary<Type, T> {

    public override void Add<C>(T instanceOfType) {
        base.Add(typeof(C), instanceOfType);
    }

}
```

Specific questions:

- Is this the correct/best approach?
- What should I do to facilitate retrieving elements?
- If the Add() method is correct, is there any way to enforce that C is a subclass of T?

Updated code to reflect Ondrej's suggestions:

```
class TypedList<Abstract> : IList<Abstract> {

    protected Dictionary<Type, Abstract> data;

    public void TypedList() {
        data = new Dictionary<Type, Abstract>();
    }

    public void Add<Concrete>(Concrete instanceOfType) where Concrete : Abstract {
        data.Add(typeof(Concrete), instanceOfType);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do mean a singleton for each type?

Comment: There can be multiple instances of typedList containing different instances of the same class.  So it won't be one-per-class-per-VM, no.

Comment: In the updated version you should use `typeof(Concrete)`, not `typeof(Abstract)`. Also note it's a common convension to start type parameters with `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many months later and I think I've come up with a really nice solution, which is to use a collection I wasn't aware of initially `KeyedCollection`:

```
public class TypedSet<AbstractType> : KeyedCollection<Type, AbstractType> {

    protected override Type GetKeyForItem(AbstractType item) {
        return item.GetType();
    }

}
```

Very conscice and doesn't require any stitching of different types of collection classes together.  Makes for slightly more idiomatic code as well as `KeyedCollection` is abstract and requires implementation of `GetKeyForItem`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach generally seems fine. However, I'd consider hiding the `Dictionary<Type, T>` as a private field and reimplementing the interface you want. It needs not to be `IDictionary<Type, T>`, it may as well be just a `IList<T>`.

Another option is to use `List<T>` for internal storage, and `HashSet<Type>` to maintain the set of types of items in the list. Such underlying storage may be better suited in case `IList<T>` is the wanted interface of `TypedList<T>`, solving the “missing index” problem with a dictionary.

Also, the `Add<C>` method declaration seems incorrect. You should declare it as:

```
public override void Add<C>(C instanceOfType) where C : T {
    base.Add(typeof(C), instanceOfType);
}
```

That makes sure `C` will be an ancestor of `T`. In your original declaration `C` could have been any type, possibly unrelated to `T`.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for mapping the remaining methods of `IDictionary` through to the wrapped `IList`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to contain what I gleaned from your suggestion.  Does that look better?

Comment: I'd implement `IList<T>` in the most straightforward manner possible, respecting the unique semantics imposed by the “single-value-per-type-key” constraint. The implementation should be trivial.

Comment: Is it any issue that `IList` uses intergers for indexes whereas I'm using `Type`?

Comment: That may be an issue. You can emulate it (maitain an order), use hashcode (and live with the fact indexes will be sparse), or use another underlying storage (see the updated answer).

Comment: Here's what I've got right now: https://gist.github.com/atrauzzi/8242870

I'm not sure I understand how I'd use `HashSet` for this solution.  I'd have to keep a mapping of types to instances eventually, which keeps me coming back to `Dictionary`?

Comment: Also worth noting that I should maybe be calling my class `TypedSet` not `TypedList`?

Comment: Well that really depends on the semantics of your classe'es interface. This is not clear from your original question, so treat my answer as suggestions of the various possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, the collection doesn't care much for order.  It's only concerned with membership and retrieval.  Which makes me think the `Dictionary` approach and an external interface of a `Set` may work?

Comment: Yes. Or an `ICollection<T>`…

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the constraint you're looking for!

class TypedList : Dictionary {

```
public override void Add<C>(T instanceOfType) where C : T{
    base.Add(typeof(C), instanceOfType);
}
```

}

However, I'm wondering why you're not just using a dictionary straight up?
I.E. the dictionary that you're subclassing should behave the way you waint?